# Removing different types of Items from PriorityQueue according to some conditions

Tags: java, iterator, priority-queue

I am try to exam two kind of links inside my Priority Queuue structure named `interLinks` and `intraLinks`. According to method `URLremoveCondition()` below, I am try to remove all these two kind of URL links `interLinks` and `intraLinks`  from my `PQueue` if they reached `MaxWaitTime` which I setted it to `10 Seconds`  the method will remove these links.

But the problem is that the method  `URLremoveCondition()` is removing only `interLinks` from `PQueue` and not removing `intraLinks`. How can I fix this problem to remove both of `interLinks` and `intraLinks` ?

This is my method `URLremoveCondition()`

```
public static PriorityQueue <LinkNodeLight> PQueue = new PriorityQueue <> (); 
private static Integer MaxWaitTime = new Integer (10000); // 10 Seconds

public void URLremoveCondition() {
    synchronized (PQueue) {

            Iterator<LinkNodeLight> iterator = PQueue.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                LinkNodeLight URL = iterator.next();

                    long URLWaitingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - URL.enqueTime.getMillis();
                    if(URLWaitingTime > MaxWaitTime){
                        iterator.remove();

                        System.out.println("DELETED NODE: " + URL.url + " WAITTIME: " +  Long.toString(URLWaitingTime));
                    }                 
            } 
        }   
    }
```

and this is my class `LinkNodeLight` :

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class LinkNodeLight implements Comparable<LinkNodeLight> {
protected String url;
protected float weight;
protected DateTime enqueTime;
protected boolean interLinks;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public float getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(float weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public DateTime getEnqueTime() {
    return enqueTime;
}


public LinkNodeLight(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public boolean isInterLinks() {
    return interLinks;
}

public void setInterLinks(boolean interLinks) {
    this.interLinks = interLinks;
}

public void setEnqueTime(DateTime enqueTime) {
    this.enqueTime = enqueTime;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(LinkNodeLight link) {

    if (this.weight < link.weight) return 1;
     else if (this.weight > link.weight) return -1;
        return 0;

}
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here I am creating `interLinks` and `intraLinks`

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


 public class URLWeight {

 public static List<LinkNodeLight> weight(LinkNode sourceLink, List<LinkNodeLight> links) {

    List<LinkNodeLight> interLinks = new LinkedList<>();
    List<LinkNodeLight> intraLinks = new LinkedList<>();

    for (LinkNodeLight link : links) {
        if (isIntraLink(sourceLink, link)) {
            intraLinks.add(link);
            link.setInterLinks(false);
        } else {
            interLinks.add(link);
            link.setInterLinks(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where and how do you create the list?

Comment: Nothing in the code you presented distinguishes between `LinkNodeLight` instances based on the values of their `interLinks` properties, so I'm inclined not to believe that any of it is responsible for the behavior you observe.  Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want help.

Comment: @nautical I am creating the list inside URLWeight.java I will edit the question and add regarding codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by generating `getter` and `setter` for `intraLinks` to `LinkNodeLight`class

```
protected boolean intraLinks;

public boolean isIntraLinks() {
    return intraLinks;
}

public void setInterLinks(boolean interLinks) {
    this.interLinks = interLinks;
}


public void setIntraLinks(boolean intraLinks) {
    this.intraLinks = intraLinks;
}
```